# using HLSL in XNA

Tags: c#, opencv, xna, hlsl, emgucv

I'm looking to write a perona malik anisotropic filter and it looks like I'll need to utilize the gpu for performance reasons. Long story short, I want to know how to use HLSL in xna to to GPGPU tasks.

I'm looking for some code snippets to move some data on to the GPU, process it frame by frame, then return it so I can do other stuff with it.

From what I've read, I need to use "[ping-ponging](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/512643-ping-ponging-using-directx-hlsl-and-c/)"

**EDIT**

This is what I have so far

**C#**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Processors;

namespace HotplateTest
{
    public class XNAClass : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        RenderTarget2D Target;
        RenderTarget2D Output;
        Effect physicsEffect;

        Vector4[] positions;

        public XNAClass()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        }

        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            Target = new RenderTarget2D(graphics.GraphicsDevice, 10, 10, false, SurfaceFormat.Vector4, DepthFormat.None);
            Output = new RenderTarget2D(graphics.GraphicsDevice, 10, 10, false, SurfaceFormat.Vector4, DepthFormat.None);

            positions = new Vector4[100];
            for (int i = 0; i < positions.Length; i++)
            {
                positions[i] = new Vector4(i);
            }

            Target.SetData<Vector4>(positions);

            base.Initialize();
        }

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            base.LoadContent();
            physicsEffect = Content.Load<Effect>("shader");
        }

        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {

            GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(Target); 
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);
            physicsEffect.Techniques[0].Passes[0].Apply();
            physicsEffect.Parameters["oldPositionTexture"].SetValue(Output); 
            physicsEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();

            GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
            Target.GetData<Vector4>(positions);


            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

**HLSL**

```
texture oldPositionTexture;

sampler oldPositionSampler = sampler_state
{
    Texture = < oldPositionTexture >;

    MipFilter = POINT;
    MinFilter = POINT;
    MagFilter = POINT;
    ADDRESSU = CLAMP;
    ADDRESSV = CLAMP;
};

struct VertexShaderInput
{
    float4 Position : POSITION;
    float2 Tex  : TEXCOORD0;
};

struct VertexShaderOutput
{
    float4 Position : POSITION;
    float2 Tex  : TEXCOORD0;
};

// input texture dimensions
static const float w = 10;
static const float h = 10;

static const float2 pixel = float2(1.0 / w, 1.0 / h);
static const float2 halfPixel = float2(pixel.x / 2, pixel.y / 2);

VertexShaderOutput VS(VertexShaderInput input)
{
    VertexShaderOutput output = (VertexShaderOutput)0;

    output.Tex = input.Tex; 

    return output;
}

float4 PS1(VertexShaderOutput input) : COLOR0
{
    float2 myV = input.Tex;
    float myPosAndMass = tex2D(oldPositionSampler, myV);

    return float4(myPosAndMass, myPosAndMass, myPosAndMass, myPosAndMass);
}

technique Technique1
{
    pass Pass0
    {
        VertexShader = compile vs_2_0 VS();
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 PS1();
    }
}
```

I get an error message

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.dll
>
> Additional information: The type you are using for T in this method is
>   an invalid size for this resource.

Interestingly when I use Single instead of Vector4 in the C# code, the error message does not occur. Of course this means that the results calculated in the positions variable are now useless because they are interpreted as single when they are really vector4.

Comment: I think I'm missing some conceptual understanding of how shaders work.

Comment: I've managed to get this fixed over at [Game Development][1]


  [1]: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/59619/gpgpu-programming-using-hlsl-and-xna/59671#59671

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**C#**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using Emgu.Util;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;

namespace HLSLTest
{
    public delegate void Disp();

    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game
    /// </summary>
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        Capture cap = new Capture("output.avi");
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        RenderTarget2D renOutput;

        Vector4[] gpuStore = new Vector4[1920 * 1080];

        Effect effect;
        QuadRender quad;
        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
        /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
        /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
        /// and initialize them as well.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

            base.Initialize();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
        /// all of your content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
            quad = new QuadRender(GraphicsDevice);

            renOutput = new RenderTarget2D(GraphicsDevice, 1920, 1080, false, SurfaceFormat.Vector4, DepthFormat.Depth24);

            effect = Content.Load<Effect>("Shader");

            base.LoadContent();

            // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
        /// all content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
        /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // Allows the game to exit
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();

            // TODO: Add your update logic here

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            Image<Bgr, Byte> video = cap.QueryFrame();
            using (Image<Bgra, float> vid2 = video.Convert<Bgra, float>())
            {

                Texture2D t = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, video.Width, video.Height, false, SurfaceFormat.Vector4);
                t.SetData<byte>(vid2.Bytes);

                GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(renOutput);
                effect.Parameters["Input0"].SetValue(t);
                quad.RenderFullScreenQuad(effect);
                for (int i = 0; i < effect.Techniques.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < effect.Techniques[i].Passes.Count; j++)
                    {
                        effect.Techniques[i].Passes[j].Apply();
                    }
                }

                GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
                renOutput.GetData<Vector4>(gpuStore);
            }

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace HLSLTest
{
    internal sealed class QuadRender
    {
        private VertexPositionTexture[] verts;
        private GraphicsDevice myDevice;
        private short[] ib = null;

        ///
        /// Loads the quad.
        ///
        ///
        public QuadRender(GraphicsDevice device)
        {
            myDevice = device;         
            verts = new VertexPositionTexture[]
            {
                new VertexPositionTexture
                (
                    new Vector3(0,0,0),
                    new Vector2(1,1)
                ),
                new VertexPositionTexture
                (
                    new Vector3(0,0,0),
                    new Vector2(0,1)
                ),
                new VertexPositionTexture
                (
                    new Vector3(0,0,0),
                    new Vector2(0,0)
                ),
                new VertexPositionTexture
                (
                    new Vector3(0,0,0),
                    new Vector2(1,0)
                )
            };

            ib = new short[] { 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0 };
        }             

        ///
        /// Draws the fullscreen quad.
        ///
        ///
        public void RenderFullScreenQuad(Effect effect)
        {
            effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();
            RenderQuad(Vector2.One * -1, Vector2.One);
        }

        public void RenderQuad(Vector2 v1, Vector2 v2)
        {          

            verts[0].Position.X = v2.X;
            verts[0].Position.Y = v1.Y;

            verts[1].Position.X = v1.X;
            verts[1].Position.Y = v1.Y;

            verts[2].Position.X = v1.X;
            verts[2].Position.Y = v2.Y;

            verts[3].Position.X = v2.X;
            verts[3].Position.Y = v2.Y;

            myDevice.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, verts, 0, 4, ib, 0, 2);
        }
    }
}
```

**HLSL**

```
texture2D Input0;
sampler2D Input0Sampler = sampler_state
{
    Texture = <Input0>;
    MinFilter = Point;
    MagFilter = Point;
    MipFilter = Point;
    AddressU = Clamp;
    AddressV = Clamp;
};

texture2D Input1;
sampler2D Input1Sampler = sampler_state
{
    Texture = <Input1>;
    MinFilter = Point;
    MagFilter = Point;
    MipFilter = Point;
    AddressU = Clamp;
    AddressV = Clamp;
};

texture2D Input2;
sampler2D Input2Sampler = sampler_state
{
    Texture = <Input2>;
    MinFilter = Point;
    MagFilter = Point;
    MipFilter = Point;
    AddressU = Clamp;
    AddressV = Clamp;
};

texture2D Input3;
sampler2D Input3Sampler = sampler_state
{
    Texture = <Input3>;
    MinFilter = Point;
    MagFilter = Point;
    MipFilter = Point;
    AddressU = Clamp;
    AddressV = Clamp;
};


struct VertexShaderInput
{
    float4 Position : POSITION0;
    float2 TextureCoordinate : TEXCOORD0;
};

struct VertexShaderOutput
{
    float4 Position : POSITION0;
    float2 TextureCoordinate : TEXCOORD0;
};

struct PixelShaderOutput
{
    // TODO: Optionally add/remove output indices to match GPUProcessor.numOutputs
    float4 Index0 : COLOR0;
};

// input texture dimensions
static const float w = 1920;
static const float h = 1080;

static const float2 pixel = float2(1.0 / w, 1.0 / h);
static const float2 halfPixel = float2(pixel.x / 2, pixel.y / 2);


VertexShaderOutput VertexShaderFunction(VertexShaderInput vsInput)
{
    //VertexShaderOutput output;

    //output.Position = vsInput.Position;
    //output.TextureCoordinate = vsInput.TextureCoordinate;

    VertexShaderOutput output;
    vsInput.Position.x =  vsInput.Position.x - 2*halfPixel.x;
    vsInput.Position.y =  vsInput.Position.y + 2*halfPixel.y;
    output.Position = vsInput.Position;
    output.TextureCoordinate = vsInput.TextureCoordinate ;
    return output;


    //return output;
}

PixelShaderOutput PixelShaderFunction(VertexShaderOutput psInput)
{
    PixelShaderOutput output;
    // TODO: Optionally add/remove samples to match GPUProcessor.numInputs
    float4 input0 = tex2D(Input0Sampler, psInput.TextureCoordinate);
    //float4 input1 = tex2D(Input0Sampler, psInput.TextureCoordinate);
    //float4 input2 = tex2D(Input0Sampler, psInput.TextureCoordinate);
    //float4 input3 = tex2D(Input0Sampler, psInput.TextureCoordinate);

    // your calculations go here

    // TODO: Optionally add/remove outputs to match GPUProcessor.numOutputs
    output.Index0 = input0;//float4(100,200,13,24);//input0;

    return output;
}

technique Verlet
{
    pass Go
    {
        VertexShader = compile vs_2_0 VertexShaderFunction();
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 PixelShaderFunction();
    }
}
```